# Symbolic multiple Integrals not delivering expected zero result

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, function-construction, symbolic

Consider the following function defined as a double-integral:

$ int_{2D}(h)=\int_0^h \int_0^{t_1}f(t_1,t_2) dt_2 dt_1 $.

Clearly,
$int_{2D}(0)=0$
as long as $f(t_1,t_2)$ is well-behaved.

The previous function can be easily translated into Mathematica's language

`int2d[h_]:=Integrate[f[t1,t2],{t1,0,h},{t2,0,t1}]`

Now, evaluate

`int2d[0]`

to obtain the output

`\!\( \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(0\)]\( \*SubsuperscriptBox[\(\[Integral]\), \(0\), \(t1\)]f[t1, t2] \[DifferentialD]t2 \[DifferentialD]t1\)\)`

The previous expression suggests that Mathematica is giving the literal result, namely

$ int_{2D}(0)=\int_0^0 \int_0^{t_1}f(t_1,t_2) dt_2 dt_1 $

Is there any way that Mathematica provides a vanishing result (as it should be)? Is it necessary to define rules in the spirit of https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/38171/90163 ?

(I found one way to solve it, but I would like to avoid the approach that I am presenting below.
By a simple change of variables rewrite $int_{2D}$ as

$int_{2D}(h)=h^2\int_0^1 \int_0^{1}f(hs_1,hs_1 s_2) ds_2 ds_1 $,

and then translate the above expression into Mathematica)

This situation contrasts with the one-dimensional case, where one defines

`int1D[h_]=Integrate[f[t1],{t1,0,h}]`

Thus, evaluating `int1D(0)` one obtains `0`.

Comment: The double integral does directly evaluate to zero if you exchange the order of integration.

Answer (score 6):

In Mathematica, the command

```
Integrate[g[x, y], {x, 0, a}, {y, 0, b}]
```

Is as if one wrote

$$
\int_{0}^{a}\left(  \int_{0}^{b}g\left(  x,y\right)  dy\right)  dx
$$

And not

$$
\int_{0}^{b}\left(  \int_{0}^{a}g\left(  x,y\right)  dx\right)  dy
$$

Notice the order. i.e The *inner* limit $\{x,0,a\}$ in the command is
used on the *outer* integral and the *outer* limit in the command
$\{y,0,b\}$ is used on the *inner* integral.

This is confusing but known. There are number of posts on this in this forum if you search.

Because of this, your call to `int2d` gives

```
int2d[h_] := Integrate[f[t1, t2], {t1, 0, h}, {t2, 0, t1}]
int2d[0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

And because the inner integral does not evaluate the whole thing remains unevaluated. You can fix this if you change the order as mentioned in
comment.

But the easy solution is to use explicit Integrate command for each.  Now you decide on the order explicitly. Like this

```
intV1[h_] := Integrate[Integrate[f[t1, t2], {t2, 0, t1}], {t1, 0, h}]
intV2[h_] := Integrate[Integrate[f[t1, t2], {t1, 0, h}], {t2, 0, t1}]
```

Both now will give zero

```
intV1[0]
intV2[0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

see

[Why does Mathematica list the variables in a double integral backwards?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45912/why-does-mathematica-list-the-variables-in-a-double-integral-backwards)

[Order of integration changes output of indefinite multiple integral in Mathematica 7](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/17196/order-of-integration-changes-output-of-indefinite-multiple-integral-in-mathemati)

[How to convert Integrate[Integrate[...] ...] into multiple integral](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/262185/how-to-convert-integrateintegrate-into-multiple-integral)

Comment: Thank you @Nasser. I was aware about the particular order that Mathematica requieres when writing multiple integrals. I see, so the inner integral is not evaluated, that explains everything.  As a comment `intV2[h_]` is a different integral, limits of integration were not properly modified after the change of order. In any case using `Integrate` twice does the job.